# Optaplanner: Define constraints dynamically based on PlanningSolution property

Tags: optaplanner

Assume I have [this](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.38.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html) implementation of a `ConstraintProvider`.

```java
package com.example.solver;

import com.example.domain.Lesson;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScore;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.Constraint;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintFactory;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintProvider;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.Joiners;

public class TimeTableConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] {
                roomConflict(constraintFactory),
                teacherConflict(constraintFactory),
        };
    }

    private Constraint roomConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.from(Lesson.class)
                .join(Lesson.class,
                        Joiners.equal(Lesson::getTimeslot),
                        Joiners.equal(Lesson::getRoom),
                        Joiners.lessThan(Lesson::getId))
                .penalize("Room conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }

    private Constraint teacherConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.from(Lesson.class)
                .join(Lesson.class,
                        Joiners.equal(Lesson::getTimeslot),
                        Joiners.equal(Lesson::getTeacher),
                        Joiners.lessThan(Lesson::getId))
                .penalize("Teacher conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }
```

Assume that I only want to constrain with `roomConflict` in case my `PlanningSolution` has boolean property `considerRoomConflict`. Likewise, I only want to use `roomConflict` in case my `PlanningSolution` has boolean property `considerTeacherConflict`.

Assume that I would have 5 such conditionals. What would be a good implementation hereof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@ConstraintConfiguration` with `@ConstraintWeight`. Some of the optaplanner-examples use it.

```
@ConstraintWeight("Teacher conflict")
// To disable, change to HardSoftScore.ZERO
private HardSoftScore teacherConflict = HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD;
```

Then use `penalizeConfigurable()` instead of `penalize()`:

```
constraintFactory.from(Lesson.class)
.join(...)
.penalizeConfigurable("Teacher conflict")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Geoffrey. You are great at supporting the community. I hope you see it pay off. For me this little thing was a big help in my project. Thank you.

Comment: Consider buying [a RH support subscription](https://www.optaplanner.org/product/services.html) :)

Comment: I have connected to a Red Hat representative in the UK. He has not answered for a week now. I have reconnected with him now and hope to get a chance to support OptaPlanner.